# Gocart codeigniter Installation issues

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with installing go cart on Linux live server cpanel
   When i install go cart on Linux server the empty page occurred and nothing happens

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on error reporting in php.ini.
In ubuntu php.ini is here: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Try to search lines like this

```
 ; error_reporting

error_reporting = XXXXXXXXX
```

and replace to :

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & E_NOTICE & E_STRICT
```

See also https://www.php.net/function.error_reporting

@edit

You can also add following code to script:

```
    <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you don't have the php_intl extension enabled on your server, which gocart requires (from version 2.3 I believe). Without error reporting on, all you will get is a white screen.

If you have access to your php.ini file, make sure this line is uncommented;

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

If you don't have access to the php.ini file, then you will need to ask your hosts if they can enable this for you.